# Other function will not appear when I not select Lain-Lain(Others)

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my coding. My Field PPD /Sekolah / Lain-Lain not appear if I not selected Lain-Lain at Tujuan field and my javascript for alamat is not functioning when I select LAIN-LAIN at PPD / SEKOLAH / LAIN-LAIN field(The text box did not appear like tujuan). Please someone help me

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Borang Daftar Kehadiran</title>
      <script>
         function semak() {
             if(document.getElementById('tujuan').value == 'LAIN-LAIN') {
                 document.getElementById('lain2').style.display='block';
             }
             else {
                 document.getElementById('lain2').style.display='none';
             }
         };
         function alamat() {
             if(document.getElementById('alamat').value == 'LAIN-LAIN') {
                 document.getElementById('lain').style.display='block';
             }
             else {
                 document.getElementById('lain').style.display='none';
             }
         };

      </script>
   </head>
   <style type="text/css">
      body {
      margin-left: 0px;
      margin-top: 0px;
      margin-right: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 0px;
      background: #98e4fe;
      background: url(image/Pusat-Kegiatan-Guru.png);
      display:cover;
      }
   </style>
   <body>
      <div id="container">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div class="mainbody">
         <div class="form">
            <h4>BORANG KEHADIRAN</h4>
            <h6>Lengkapkan kesemua maklumat di bawah</h6>
            <h5><label for="name">Nama Penuh</label></h5>
            <input type="text" id="nama" name="nama" placeholder="Contoh : ALI BIN ABU (Maksimum 50 Aksara)" style="text-transform: uppercase" maxlength="50">
            <h5><label for="no_kad">No Kad Pengenalan Baru</label></h5>
            <input type="text" id="no_kad" name="no_kad" placeholder="Contoh : 888888114444" maxlength="12">
            <h5><label for="no_tel">No Telefon</label></h5>
            <input type="text" id="no_tel" name="no_tel" placeholder="CONTOH : 0123456789 (MAKSIMUM 14 AKSARA)" maxlength="14">
            <h5><label for="tujuan">Tujuan</label></h5>
            <select id="tujuan" onChange='semak()' name="tujuan">
               <option value="MESYUARAT">MESYUARAT</option>
               <option value="TAKLIMAT">TAKLIMAT</option>
               <option value="BENGKEL">BENGKEL</option>
               <option value="KURSUS">KURSUS</option>
               <option value="PERTANDINGAN">PERTANDINGAN</option>
               <option value="TEMUDUGA">TEMUDUGA</option>
               <option value="LAIN-LAIN">LAIN-LAIN</option>
            </select>
            <div id='lain2' style="display: none">
               <input type='text' placeholder="Nyatakan">
               <h5><label for="alamat">PPD / Sekolah / Lain-lain</label></h5>
               <select id="alamat" name="alamat" onChange="alamat">
                  <option value="SK SG SENTEBU">SK SG SENTEBU</option>
                  <option value="SK ABANG HAJI MATAHIR">SK ABANG HAJI MATAHIR</option>
                  <option value="SK MANDOR ARIS">SK MANDOR ARIS</option>
                  <option value="SK BUKIT KINYAU">SK BUKIT KINYAU</option>
                  <option value="SK SARIKEI">SK SARIKEI</option>
                  <option value="SK UDIN">SK UDIN</option>
                  <option value="SK ADIN">SK ADIN</option>
                  <option value="SK BALONG">SK BALONG</option>
                  <option value="SK PENGHULU ANDIN">SK PENGHULU ANDIN</option>
                  <option value="SK ST ANDREW">SK ST. ANDREW</option>
                  <option value="SK ASSUN">SK ASSUN</option>
                  <option value="SK RENTAP">SK RENTAP</option>
                  <option value="SK JAWA">SK JAWA</option>
                  <option value="SK SG PAOH">SK SG PAOH</option>
                  <option value="SK SG PETAI">SK SG PETAI</option>
                  <option value="SK TANAH PUTIH">SK TANAH PUTIH</option>
                  <option value="SK SELANGAN">SK SELANGAN</option>
                  <option value="SK MUARA PAYANG">SK MUARA PAYANG</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) CHUNG HIEN">SJK(C) CHUNG HIEN</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) TIONG HO">SJK(C) TIONG HO</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SZE LU">SJK(C) SZE LU</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) MINAR">SJK(C) MINAR</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) NAM KIEW">SJK(C) NAM KIEW</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU LOK">SJK(C) SU LOK</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) KIEW MANG">SJK(C) KIEW MANG</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) HUA KEE">SJK(C) HUA KEE</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) HUA NAM">SJK(C) HUA NAM</option>
                  <option value="SK AGAMA SARIKEI">SK AGAMA SARIKEI</option>
                  <option value="SK ST ANNE">SK ST ANNE</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) BULAT">SJK(C) BULAT</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) KWANG CHIEN">SJK(C) KWANG CHIEN</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU HING">SJK(C) SU HING</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU KWONG">SJK(C) SU KWONG</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU MING">SJK(C) SU MING</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU TAK">SJK(C) SU TAK</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SIUNG HA">SJK(C) SIUNG HA</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) WAH MAN">SJK(C) WAH MAN</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SING MING">SJK(C) SING MING</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU LEE">SJK(C) SU LEE</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SU DOK">SJK(C) SU DOK</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) SAN MING">SJK(C) SAN MING</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) MING TAK">SJK(C) MING TAK</option>
                  <option value="SJK(C) ST MARTIN">SJK(C) ST MARTIN</option>
                  <option value="SK METHODIST ANGLO-CHINESE">SK METHODIST ANGLO-CHINESE</option>
                  <option value="SMK SARIKEI BARU">SMK SARIKEI BARU</option>
                  <option value="SMK BANDAR SARIKEI">SMK BANDAR SARIKEI</option>
                  <option value="SMK SG PAOH">SMK SG PAOH</option>
                  <option value="SMK TINGGI SARIKEI">SMK TINGGI SARIKEI</option>
                  <option value="SMK ST ANTHONY">SMK ST ANTHONY</option>
                  <option value="LAIN-LAIN">LAIN-LAIN</option>
               </select>
               <div id='lain' style="display: none">
                  <input type='text' placeholder="Nyatakan">
               </div>
               <input type="submit" value="Hantar">
               </form>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div id="footer"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onChange="alamat"` doesn't call the function.

Comment: I already add onChange="alamat()". It working. But Field name PPD/Sekolah/Lain not appear if user not select LAIN-LAIN at Tujuan filed.

Comment: I know. Just I cannot understand why field after TUJUAN is not visible. If I choose LAIN-LAIN, then the field PPD will appear. If I not adding the javascript, all fields are visible. Because, if user select others, they wil insert other value in a new text box